# Proj4Leaflet transform from 4326 to 3857 in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, proj4js, epsg

I am working on Leaflet from last week and this issue is killing me.

The database returns coordinates to create a Leaflet marker (working with default Map.CRS EPSG3857), so I decide to transform the dataBase coordinates 4326 to 3857 with proj4js:

```
var iarCoordinate = [-76.495207812, 3.429960207],
    obSource = new proj4.Proj('EPSG:4326'),
    obDest = new proj4.Proj('EPSG:3857'),        
    obResult = new proj4.Point(iarCoordinate);
proj4.transform(obSource, obDest, obResult);
//obResult = [-8515407.581757482, 382049.6844491562]
```

> These *[-8515407.581757482, 382049.6844491562]* do not represents the correct point.

If I reverse the initial 4326 coordinates [3.429960207,-76.495207812] and directly set to the marker, it shows perfect (without any proj4 tranformation).

**1. Why that transform isn't working on Leaflet or what should I do to make it work?**

**2. Why reversing the coordinates it seems to work?**

**3. How should be the right way to solve the issue?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaflet uses latitude-longitude, whereas proj4 uses longitude-latitude (or, more generically, the axis order specified in the projection definition, which for most projections is easting-northing).

Yes, [some software uses lat-long and other software uses long-lat](https://macwright.org/lonlat/) and it's confusing.

If you're going to use only `EPSG:4326` and `EPSG:3857`, consider using Leaflet's built-in `L.CRS.EPSG3857.project` and `L.CRS.EPSG.3857.unproject`, remember to check [Leaflet's documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#crs). That way you'll work with one consistent axis order.

Comment: Thanks @IvanSanchez, I just realized that the coordinates I receive from the database (which uses longitude-latitude in the WGS84 format) when inverted (latitude-longitude) Leaflet (EPSG: 3758) is able to understand them and transform them to paint them on the map.